# What is an xs:NCName type and when should it be used?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I ran one of my xml files through a schema generator and everything generated was what was expected, with the exception of one node:

```
<xs:element name="office" type="xs:NCName"/>
```

What exactly is `xs:NCName`?  And why would one use it, rather `xs:string`?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

[NCName](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#NCName) is non-colonized name e.g. "name". Compared to QName which is qualified name e.g. "ns:name". If your names are not supposed to be qualified by different namespaces, then they are NCNames.

xs:string puts no restrictions on your names at all, but xs:NCName basically disallows ":" to appear in the string.

Comment: empty string is also disallowed in `xs:NCName`

Answer (score 130):

@skyl practically provoked me to write this answer so please mind the redundancy.

`NCName` stands for "non-colonized name". NCName can be defined as an XML Schema regular expression `[\i-[:]][\c-[:]]*`

#### ...and what does that regex mean?

`\i` and `\c` are multi-character escapes defined in XML Schema definition.
http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-ccesN
`\i` is the escape for the set of initial XML name characters and `\c` is the set of XML name characters.  `[\i-[:]]` means a set that consist of the set `\i` excluding a set that consist of the colon character `:`. So in plain English it would mean "any initial character, but not `:`". The whole regular expression reads as "One initial XML name character, but not a colon, followed by zero or more XML name characters, but not a colon."

#### Practical restrictions of an NCName

The practical restrictions of NCName are that it cannot contain several symbol characters like `:`, `@`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `/`, `+`, `,`, `;`, whitespace characters or different parenthesis. Furthermore an NCName cannot begin with a number, dot or minus character although they can appear later in an NCName.

#### Where are NCNames needed

In namespace conformant XML documents all names must be either qualified names or NCNames. **The following values must be NCNames (not qualified names):**

- namespace prefixes
- values representing an ID
- values representing an IDREF
- values representing a NOTATION
- processing instruction targets
- entity names

Comment: The line 'Furthermore an NCName cannot begin with a number' helped me understand that a number can't be an 'xs:ID'

Comment: How can I convert that expression to a programming language like Java or JS?

Comment: @calbertts, See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: You can check wether it is a regular CName with the regex: "[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_][\\w\\.\\-\\d]*". That means. the value should start with a letter or underscore and then contains of words, dots, dashes, underscores, digits. You can try it at: https://regexr.com/

Comment: My regex given above only handles latin letters.
If you want the full check on NCNames according to the specification https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#NT-NCName you should use this class: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/CheckswhetherthesuppliedStringisanNCNameNamespaceClassifiedName.htm

Answer (score 30):

Practically speaking...

**Allowed characters:** `-`, `.`, `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`, `H`, `I`, `J`, `K`, `L`, `M`, `N`, `O`, `P`, `Q`, `R`, `S`, `T`, `U`, `V`, `W`, `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `_`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g`, `h`, `i`, `j`, `k`, `l`, `m`, `n`, `o`, `p`, `q`, `r`, `s`, `t`, `u`, `v`, `w`, `x`, `y`, `z`
; plus all non-ASCII characters matching `\p{L}+`.

Also, digits, `-` and `.` cannot be used as the first character of the value.

**Disallowed characters:**  , `!`, `"`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `/`, `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `@`, `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `` `,` {`,` |`,` }`,` ~`

Comment: I think this is missing lots of allowed characters like, for example, é or ø.

Comment: To cover those non-ascii cases, it should include \p{L}+ as part of the character set

Comment: Digits cannot be used as the first character, either.

Answer (score 8):

http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77215.html

No spaces or colons.  Allows "_" and "-".

You would use this instead of string so that you can validate that the value is limited to what is allowed.  It maps well to certain conventions for name/identifier like django's concept of "slug", for instance.

I upvote the person who `[\i-[:]][\c-[:]]*` translates into English for us.

Comment: I added an answer that translates `[\i-[:]][\c-[:]]*` into English. Go ahead and upvote, as you promised ;)