# delcaration of name starting with numbers

Tags: java

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://temenos.com/SECTORTWS" xmlns:hfp="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-hasFacetAndProperty" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://temenos.com/SECTORTWS">
    <xsd:element name="row" type="SECTORTWSType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <hfp:hasProperty name="locked" value="no"/>
                <hfp:hasProperty name="useschema" value="no"/>
                <hfp:hasProperty name="register" value="no"/>
                <hfp:hasProperty name="aaPropertyName" value=""/>
            </xsd:appinfo>
            <xsd:documentation>This is the top level element for the record data</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="SECTORTWSType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>This complex type represents the T24 data for the SECTOR table</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="gDESCRIPTION">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:element id="DESCRIPTION" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="123DESC">
                            <xsd:annotation>
                                <xsd:appinfo>
                                    <hfp:hasProperty name="fielddatatype" value="string"/>
                                    <hfp:hasProperty name="fieldname" value="DESCRIPTION"/>
                                </xsd:appinfo>
                                <xsd:documentation>DESCRIPTION</xsd:documentation>
                            </xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:maxLength value="35"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="g" type="xsd:positiveInteger" use="optional"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="id">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:maxLength value="250"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

> name="123DESC"

[Element names must be no-colon-names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256118%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ([NCName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631396/what-is-an-xsncname-type-and-when-should-it-be-used)) as defined in the XML Namespaces specification and cannot start with a digit.