# Strange exception when id of the bean is set empty in spring's bean.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans, spring-config

Just for curiosity, I left the id of the bean inside bean.xml empty. I was expecting the exception something like "bean id is not defined" or "bean id can't be null"
But actually, I got the below exception -

```
cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for 'NCName'.
```

What does it indicate?

Full exception is -

```
06:26:18.262 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 13 in XML document from class path resource [beans.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 94; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for 'NCName'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
```

The content of bean.xml is

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id = "employee" class = "com.test.springboot.spring_boot_example.Employee" >
      <property name = "name" value = "Arvind"/>
       <property name = "address" ref = "address"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id = "" class = "com.test.springboot.spring_boot_example.Address" scope="prototype">
      <property name = "houseNumber" value = "64"/>

   </bean>



</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the xml will not validate against the DTD

Since the id property is expected to be an [NCName](http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_NCName.html) the xml parser will throw the exception. An `NCName` is not allowed to be empty.

There is also an excellent q/a [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631396/what-is-an-xsncname-type-and-when-should-it-be-used) to read up more about how it's used

Comment: Thanks @juntro, I was looking for the info about NCName.